# Symfony 3.4 - ChoiceType field and same labels

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

Ok I read a lot about this one, mainly here : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19953

But I still can't get a simple solution;

I want to display a select with this data :

```
$data = [
   2 => 'Label 1',
   5 => 'Label 2',
   6 => 'Label 1', 
   11 => 'Label 3',
]
```

I use `optgroup`, so I can have several identical labels (`Label 1` here).

But how can I show them in my ChoiceType ? For now I have:

```
 $builder
       ->add('type', ChoiceType::class, [
            'label' => 'Type',
            'required' => true,
            'choices' => $options['data'],
            'choice_label' => function ($value) {
                return $value;
            },
            'choice_value' => function ($value) {
                // how to get correct value here ?
            },
        ])
```

This example show my select list with duplicatas, but values are like `0, 1, 2, 3 ....`.

And if I remove `choice_label`, it doesn't show duplicata.

I tried this :

```
# app/config.yml
framework:
    form:
        choices_as_values: false # defaults to true
```

But the option seems to not exist on Symfony 3.4. Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem *appears* to be happening when you have IDs as values from possibly entities. If they are indeed entities, please use the EntityType!!!

... that being said ...

okay, what symfony essentially does is have its choices array in the form `[ label => value ]`, which obviously is a problem when handling duplicate labels.

I believe the simplest way around this should be:

```
$new = [
   (object) ['value' => 2, 'label' => 'Label 1'],
   (object) ['value' => 5, 'label' => 'Label 2'],
   (object) ['value' => 6, 'label' => 'Label 1'], 
   (object) ['value' => 11, 'label' => 'Label 3'],
];
```

which could be generated fairly quickly via

```
$new = [];
foreach($old_choices as $value => $label) { 
    $new[] = (object) ['value' => $value, 'label' => $label];
}
```

then you can set

```
 'choices' => $new,
 'choice_label' => function($entry) { return $entry->label; },
 'choice_value' => function($entry) { return $entry->value; },
```

(or the property path)

I'm not quite certain what would be returned in the final `$form->getData()`, but I hope it's the value.

If you still want to group the values, the `group_by` option should work.

Comment: You can hope, it works ! Thanks. I found kind of same way. just a little disapointed there is no any native option

Comment: @VincentDecaux weirdly enough, it didn't work in symfony 5.0. needs to be objects ;o/